# javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active:

Tags: java, transactions, quartz-scheduler, jobs

In production after two three days we start getting following exception:

```
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f572ada:f5ff:52482a05:11a4 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f572ada:f5ff:52482a05:11a4 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >)
                at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:95)
                at com.rwsol.syb.persistence.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getPhysicalConnection(JDBCDataStore.java:146)
                ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f572ada:f5ff:52482a05:11a4 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >
                at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:370)
                at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
                at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
                at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
```

We are using a dedicated batch server for All the Nightly quartz Jobs. Because of this issue we need to restart the batch in every 4-5 days. After 2-3 days one Job fails then next day 2-3 jobs fails and at last after 4-5 days all jobs fails.

I have tried increasing the Transaction time out but with no success.

Please help me in getting this issues resolved.

Comment: We'll need to see your transaction management.

Comment: Either 1. Transaction timeout  or  2. connection leak

Comment: In the production the Transaction time out is set to 5 hr so I don't think it is an time out issue.

Comment: @anuragarya Hi, have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?